# Angular 11 with Karma and Jasmine test broken

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I recently updated my Angular project and its dependencies to the newest version.
But I have some errors when I try to run my test:

```
Error: node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter.d.ts:25:5 - error TS2416: Property 'suiteStarted' in type 'SpecReporter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CustomReporter'.
  Type '(result: import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult) => void' is not assignable to type '(result: jasmine.CustomReporterResult) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'result' and 'result' are incompatible.
      Type 'jasmine.CustomReporterResult' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult'.
        Types of property 'duration' are incompatible.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

25     suiteStarted(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter.d.ts:26:5 - error TS2416: Property 'suiteDone' in type 'SpecReporter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CustomReporter'.
  Type '(result: import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult) => void' is not assignable to type '(result: jasmine.CustomReporterResult) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'result' and 'result' are incompatible.
      Type 'jasmine.CustomReporterResult' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult'.

26     suiteDone(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
       ~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter.d.ts:27:5 - error TS2416: Property 'specStarted' in type 'SpecReporter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CustomReporter'.
  Type '(result: import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult) => void' is not assignable to type '(result: jasmine.CustomReporterResult) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'result' and 'result' are incompatible.
      Type 'jasmine.CustomReporterResult' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/davide.cividini/Projects/g3pharmacy/frontend/node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter/built/spec-reporter").CustomReporterResult'.

27     specStarted(result: CustomReporterResult): void;
```

This is the command that I run:

```
ng test --browsers=Chrome --code-coverage --karmaConfig=src/karma-dev.conf.js
```

Those are my dependencies:

```
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "^6.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
"karma-parallel": "^0.3.1",
```

And this is my *karma-dev.conf.js*:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    files: [ '../node_modules/mark.js/dist/mark.min.js' ],
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [ 'jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular' ],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : '../../../coverage/'
    },
    reporters: [ 'progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit' ],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '',
      outputFile: undefined,
      suite: '',
      useBrowserName: true,
      nameFormatter: undefined,
      classNameFormatter: undefined,
      properties: {},
      xmlVersion: null
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [ 'Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI', 'ChromeDebugging', 'HeadlessChrome' ],
    captureTimeout: 120000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [ '--no-sandbox' ]
      },
      ChromeDebugging: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333' ]
      },
      HeadlessChrome:{
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [ '--no-sandbox' ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Before with Angular 10 everythings worked well.
I also tried to replace the older Karma version but not works.
Someone can help me? Thanks everybody.

Comment: You need to share the component.ts file and component.spec.ts file where this test is failing

Comment: @OwenKelvin the tests don't failed, Karma failed to run before run the tests. Those are the errors that appears when I try to run Karma.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why is your Typescript checking the node_modules directory

Comment: @OwenKelvin I think it is loading the libraries to start testing, at the configuration level I have not touched anything unfortunately.